# Winsock data is not retrieved from an IP, but it's retrieved from a normal URL

Tags: c++, url, winsock

I have a function to get the contents of a web page with Winsock, the problem I have is that I receive the page when specifying a URL and I don't get anything when replacing it with an IP

This works:   get_Website("www.google.com");

This doesn't:  get_Website("100.111.33.77");

```
// Function
void get_Website(string url ){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET Socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    int lineCount=0;
    int rowCount=0;
    struct hostent *host;
    string get_http;


    get_http = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + url + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";


    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0){
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        //return 1;
    }

    Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    host = gethostbyname(url.c_str());

    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        cout << "Could not connect";
        system("pause");
        //return 1;
    }
    send(Socket,get_http.c_str(), strlen(get_http.c_str()),0 );

    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket,buffer,10000,0)) > 0){
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r'){

            website_HTML+=buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();

}
```

Comment: What you state in your question is just the opposite of what's in the title. Can you clarify what works, and what doesn't please.

Comment: just wondering if the IP address version needs http:// bunged on the front (maybe the www. version is defaulting to that?)

Comment: @MandyShaw this code will not work if `http://` is prepended. The code would have to parse the `url` to extract its "host" portion for use. The `url` parameter should be renamed to avoid such confusion, since it is not an actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

An IP address is not a hostname, so don't use `gethostbyname()` to resolve an IP address.  Check if the input is an IP first, and if not then resolve it as a hostname. In your example, since you are using `AF_INET`, you can simply use `inet_addr()` for that check, eg:

```
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(url.c_str());
if (Sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
{
    host = gethostbyname(url.c_str());
    if (!host) {
        // could not resolve...
        return;
    }
    if (host->h_addrtype != AF_INET) {
        // did not resolve to IPv4...
        return;
    }
    Sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *reinterpret_cast<u_long*>(host->h_addr); 
}
```

Note that a hostname can resolve to multiple IP addresses, so you should loop through the entire `host->h_addr_list` trying to `connect()` to each IP until one is successful.

Though, you really should be using [`getaddrinfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) instead, as `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, eg:

```
addrinfo hints = {};
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addrinfo *result = NULL;
if (getaddrinfo(url.c_str(), "80", &hints, &result) != 0) {
    // could not resolve...
    return;
}

bool connected = false;
for(addrinfo *addr = result; (addr != NULL) && (!connected); addr = addr->ai_next) {
    connected = (connect(Socket, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == 0);
}
freeaddrinfo(result);

if (!connected) {
    // could not connect...
    return;
}
```

Comment: When compiling I get an error: 'ADDRINFOA' was not declared in this scope, and when running the code without ADDRINFOA it enters the if   "if (!host) {"

Comment: @Freeman123 fixed the `addrinfo` issue. But if `gethostbyname()` is returning NULL then use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why. Chances are you are trying to resolve something that is not a valid hostname.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't a valid hostname. Now I'm getting the error: 'getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope, is there anything else I need to include?

Comment: @Freeman123 read the documentation I linked to. You need `#include <ws2tcpip.h>`

Comment: @Freeman123 works fine for me. Double check your copy of `ws2tcpip.h`. Also, which minimum platform does your project target? `getaddrinfo()` is supported on XP and later. If you are targetting Win2K or earlier, you also need `#include <wspiapi.h>` to emulate `getaddrinfo()`.